# Need help to figure out which algorithm to use

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics, dynamic-programming

I need an algorithm to solve a problem with the following conditions:

There is a set of "n" people and another set of "m" workshops, there are more people than workshops. Each person has chosen a subset of size "j" of the total workshops and has assigned values to each depending on how much they would like to assist that particular workshop. Now, every workshop only has a limited amount of vacancies.

Given these conditions the problem would be:

What is the best way to assign people to workshops, so that each person participates in the workshop which she considers most valuable (given the problem constraints, that is, if a person can´t participate in their first choice, then the algorithm should choose the second, third, fourth, and so on).

I think the problem is related to combinatorial optimization but I don't know much about algorithms. If anyone can tell me the name of one from which to start investigating, I'd be very grateful.

Thanks! And please excuse my english.

Comment: take a look at the 'stable marriage problem'. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem

Comment: This is called the [Assignment Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem) and is in the class of combinatorial optimization problems.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will look more into this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a matching problem with one-sided preferences (in the sense that people have preferences for the workshops, but not the other way around).

Here is an excellent paper that discusses this problem in more detail: https://mattmccutchen.net/lumc/index.html

An optimal solution to this problem isn't particularly clear. There are many different optimal (Pareto efficient) criterions. Unfortunately, the problem is NP-hard for many of them.

However, there are criterion with polynomial time algorithms. There is a nice list of these in the "Related work" section of the paper I linked.